# Oracle import data to modified table

Tags: oracle

This Is the Scenario  Schema one has table1 with columns a, b, c this table full with data

then Schema two hase table2 with same name but it has columns a b and d c columns removed and d column added

how to export data from Schema one to Schema two ?

Comment: Are you trying to export and import, or just copy data between two schemas in the same database (or even linked databases)? Are you trying to put the `c` data into the `d` column, and if so, is the data type the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Specify the columns you want to copy, and the columns into which you want
-- them to be copied
insert into schema2.table2 (cola, colb, col_modified) select cola, colb, colc from schema1.table1;

-- Or start from scratch:
-- This will also drop indexes and triggers. If you want to keep them you must
-- preserve them.
drop table schema2.table2 purge;

create table schema2.table2 as select * from schema1.table1;
-- This does not include indexes or triggers, but it does have the table contents
```